# use nhibernate pagination with the gridview control of asp .net

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, webforms

I use nhibernate 3.1 and I'd like to use the gridview control (in ASP.Net 4)

At the moment, I use the classic gridview.DataSource = xxx and gridview.DataBind() to show the data but I'd like to paginate the gridview. I know how to do it .. but if I've 10k rows, it will retrieve the 10k rows ...

Is it possible to use pagination with nhibernate without retrieving the whole data (and increase the size of the viewstate ?).

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this efficiently you could implement a [custom paging](http://lexicalclosures.blogspot.com/2009/01/paging-in-aspnet-using-nhiberate.html). Here's an [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx) which illustrates the usage of an [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx).